# Problems with JSON on iOS

Tags: iphone, json, connection, nsdata

I'm trying to parse the JSON file at this URL: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=results

The code that I have so far is as follows:

```
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)myJSON;
    for (id element in jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Element: %@", [element description]);
    }
```

This code seems to come up with an error each time (ERROR 3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)").

I'm wondering if this is a problem with the way that I'm downloading/parsing the data or if it's a problem within the actual JSON in which I have to approach it in a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `&callback=results` at the end of the URL. This causes the JSON to not start with an array or dictionary. Just be aware that if you are referencing "results" in your JSON code then you will need to remove/change that. If you diff the two JSON texts then you will see the difference (look at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

in a web browser open the result of the url you posted copy the contents then go to jsonlint.com and paste the contents then click validate. it shows you that the input is not valid json so you might have to do some additional parsing.